# Xamarin.Forms [0:] Binding: MobileUI.Models.RootObject can not be converted to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I am trying to GET data from my Web API and display it on my ListView. 
When I click the button to retrieve the data it returns me and error:

```
[0:] Binding: MobileUI.Models.RootObject can not be converted to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
```

So I made breakpoints at my Deserilization and it returns data properly but it just doesn't display on the ListView.

This are my codes :-

GetUserAsync in the ApiServices class

```
public async Task<RootObject> GetUserAsync(string accessToken)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://weburl/testrun/api/services/app/user/GetRoles");

    var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    return users;

}
```

UserViewModel

```
private readonly ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

private RootObject _users;
public RootObject Users
{
    get { return _users; }
    set
    {
        _users = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ICommand GetUsersCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
            Users = await _apiServices.GetUserAsync(accessToken);
        });
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

}

JSON response

```
{
    "result": {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Admin",
                "displayName": "Admin",
                "description": null,
                "isStatic": true,
                "permissions": [
                    "Pages.Users",
                    "Pages.Roles",
                    "Pages.Tenants"
                ],
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Tenants",
                "displayName": "Tenants",
                "description": "",
                "isStatic": false,
                "permissions": [
                    "Pages.Tenants",
                    "Pages.Users"
                ],
                "id": 12
            },
            {
                "name": "Landlord",
                "displayName": "Landlord",
                "description": "",
                "isStatic": false,
                "permissions": [
                    "Pages.Tenants",
                    "Pages.Property",
                    "Pages.Payment",
                    "Pages.Feedback",
                    "Pages.Document",
                    "Pages.LandLord",
                    "Pages.Users"
                ],
                "id": 14
            },
            {
                "name": "User",
                "displayName": "Users",
                "description": "",
                "isStatic": false,
                "permissions": [
                    "Pages.Property",
                    "Pages.Payment",
                    "Pages.Feedback",
                    "Pages.Document"
                ],
                "id": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    "targetUrl": null,
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
    "__abp": true
}
```

XAML Code

```
<Button Command="{Binding GetUsersCommand}"
        Text="Get All User Roles"
        TextColor="White"
        FontSize="20"
        BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"/>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="0,10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding result}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding success}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding error}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding displayName}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding isStatic}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Note: If I convert it to a List, an error will give the following

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MobileUI.Models.RootObject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'result', line 1, position 10.

Edit 1: Added converted JSON Response

```
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool isStatic { get; set; }
    public List<string> permissions { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public object targetUrl { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
    public bool unAuthorizedRequest { get; set; }
    public bool __abp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your json result is object.result.array.  You need to add attributes to your ```RootObject``` class to point ```items``` to ```Users``` or change the naming.  Can you also post the ```Users``` code? It may require attributes there also to help json parse out the users.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a Users code. All of the codes are already posted in the question. I don't quite understand by adding attributes to the `RootObject`.

Comment: Apologies... I meant to ask for the ```RootObject``` code.  I don't see that class listed in the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I updated the question. The RootObject class is created when I convert the JSON at JSON2CSharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your UserViewModel with this

```
private readonly ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

private ObservableCollection<Item>  _users;
public ObservableCollection<Item>  Users
{
    get { return _users; }
    set
    {
        _users = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ICommand GetUsersCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
            var user_result = await _apiServices.GetUserAsync(accessToken);
            if(user_result!=null)
            {
                 Users =new ObservableCollection<Item>(user_result.result.items);
            }
        });
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced it and it returns me an error 
`Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MobileUI.Models.Item>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MobileUI.Models.Item>' `

Comment: Try this : Users =new ObservableCollection<Item>(user_result.result.items);

Comment: Oh, I fixed it by changing 
`public class Result
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}`
to 
`public class Result
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> items { get; set; }
}`
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It's odd json converter didn't like the list but glad you fixed it. As a side note, which isn't important, you can capitalize your property names in the classes and it will still convert them from the lowercase to the uppercase c# standard without any extra work.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks for the advice, I will keep that in mind for good coding practices. :)